# Finding consecutive numbers in c#

Tags: c#

Here is my exercise..

Write a program and ask the user to enter a few numbers separated by a hyphen. Work out if the numbers are consecutive.

For example, if the input is `5-6-7-8-9`  display a message: `Consecutive`. If input `5-1-8-2`  display `Not Consecutive`.

Here is my approach.

```
namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers separate by hypen : ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            var numarray = name.Split('-');
            for (var i = 0;i<=numarray.Length-1;i++ )
            {
                if (i>1 && (Convert.ToInt32(numarray[i]) != Convert.ToInt32(numarray[i - 1])+1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not Consecutive");
                    break;
                }
                if (i == numarray.Length-1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Consecutive");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it worked. Is there any better/simplified way to this.

Comment: why do you need a for loop. you can just check if the first value and the next value is first value + 1 then we can decide if it's consecutive or not

Comment: Hi, for instnance 5-7-8-9 are consecutive or not?

Comment: @ISHIDA - That would work for just two numbers or fixed number of values. But here user can enter any number of values

Comment: @Christos - No.. `6` should be there in middle of `5` and `7`

Comment: It depends.  What constitutes "better/simplified"?  You can certainly do it in fewer lines of code (as demonstrated below) but if the result is more difficult to understand/debug/maintain, is it really better?

Comment: Does `5-4-3-2-1` is also consecutive in this scenario?

Comment: What should be returned if `5-6 -7-8-9` was the input (note the space between 6 and the - after it)?

Comment: @Dorival - No it is not.. Consider just ascending order..

Comment: @mjwills - Consider proper input is passed.. No space or any other bad characters

Comment: I think you mean "ordered" not "consecutive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most efficient way to do it:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers separate by hypen : ");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();
        var numarray = name.Split('-');
        int firstValue = Convert.ToInt32(numarray[0]);

        bool cons = true;
        for (var i = 0;i<numarray.Length;i++ )
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(numarray[i])-i != firstValue)
            {
                cons = false;                   
                break;
            }
        }
        if (cons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consecutive");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Consecutive");
        }
    }
}
```

}

https://dotnetfiddle.net/P8VGjG

Comment: What I like about this implementation, is that it only parses what it needs. If we add null checks (no input given, etc), this boost by simplicity too.

Comment: It may be faster if you replace `if (Convert.ToInt32(numarray[i])-i != firstValue)` with `if (numarray[i] == (firstValue + i).ToString())` since string -> int conversions are likely slower than int -> string conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify like this,

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers separate by hypen : ");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();
        int[] numarray = Array.ConvertAll(name.Split('-'), int.Parse); 
        if (IsSequential(numarray))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consecutive");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Consecutive");                 
        }
    }
    static bool IsSequential(int[] array)
    {
        return array.Zip(array.Skip(1), (a, b) => (a + 1) == b).All(x => x);
    }
```

Comment: This is one of those times where LINQ is really cool and all... but boy is it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an approach like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers separate by hypen : ");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();
        var numarray = name.Split('-');
        var lower = int.Parse(numarray[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(lower, numarray.Length)
            .Select(z => z.ToString()).SequenceEqual(numarray)
            ? "Consecutive"
            : "Not");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

(Even better, use TryParse just in case the first entry is not a number)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked perfectly and it is consecutive forwards and backwards.
It's simple too. It looks long because I love commenting.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This Variables checks if the secuence continues
        bool secuence = true;

        //Ask Receive Input
        Console.Write("Enter dashed numbers: ");
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split('-');

        //Convert to Integer
        int[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(input, int.Parse);

        //Loop Through all the values
        for(int i = 1; i<numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            //check if current value is +1 greater than last value
            if (numbers[i] + 1 == numbers[i - 1] || numbers[i]-1 == numbers[i - 1] && secuence == true)
            {   //continue counting if consecutive
                secuence = true;
            }
            else
            {   //Stop Counting if not consecutive
                secuence = false;
            }
        }
        //Workout the result
        if (secuence)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Numbers are consecutive");
        }
        else 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("They are not consecutive"); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Answer to the problem. It will work for the scenarios

1. 3- ==> Not Consecutive
2. 4 => Not Consecutive
3. 3-4-5-6 => Consecutive
4. 3-4-5- => Consecutive
5. 3-4-5-5-6 => N

```
using System;

namespace ConsecutiveNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number seperated by hyphen : ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var numArray = input.Split('-');
            var firstValue = numArray[0];
            var output = "Consecutive";

            if (numArray.Length > 2)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numArray[i]))
                    {
                        if (i != 0)
                        {
                            if (int.Parse(numArray[i]) - int.Parse(firstValue) == 1)
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(numArray[i]) - int.Parse(firstValue));
                                firstValue = numArray[i];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                output = "Not Consecutive";
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output = "Not Consecutive";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short and simple solution:

```
public void Question6()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter few number separated by hyphen.");
        var input = Console.ReadLine(),;
        var array = input.Split('-');
        Array.Sort(array);
        var output = "Consecutive";
        var arrayData = array[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                if (int.Parse(array[i]) - int.Parse(arrayData) == 1)
                {
                    arrayData = array[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    output = "Not Consecutive";
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.

A simple and readable approach.

```
Console.WriteLine("Type a series of number separated by hyphen: ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();

var series = input.Split("-")
       .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n));

var isConsecutive = Enumerable
      .Range(series.First(), series.Count())
      .SequenceEqual(series);

Console.WriteLine(isConsecutive ? "Consecutive"  : "Not Consecutive");
```