# find the first element of an array that is not consecutive using web forms

Tags: c#

E.g. If we have an array [1,2,3,4,6,7,8] then 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 are all consecutive but 6 is not, so that's the first non-consecutive number.
If the whole array is consecutive then return null .
The array will always have at least 2 elements 1 and all elements will be numbers. The numbers will also all be unique and in ascending order. The numbers could be positive or negative and the first non-consecutive could be either too. please help me finish this code i am new in programming. My code:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _2katas
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var input = this.txtInput.Text;
            var numarray = input.Split(',');
            int firstValue = Convert.ToInt32(numarray[0]);

            
            for (var i = 0; i < numarray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(numarray[i]) - i != firstValue)
                {
                    lblPrint.Text = "";
                }
               
                else
                {
                    lblPrint.Text = "";
                }



                if (this.rdbConsecutive.Checked == true)
                {
                    lblKataRunning.Text = "Consecutive";
                }
                else if (this.rdbStripCleaning.Checked == true)
                {
                    lblKataRunning.Text = "Strip Cleaning";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please ignore the radio buttons at the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding consecutive numbers in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340394/finding-consecutive-numbers-in-c-sharp)

Comment: "*web forms*"? do you mean winforms?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_SkipWhile__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__

Comment: @TheGeneral yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linq solution just for the fun of it:

```
static int? FindFirstNonConsecutive(IEnumerable<int> arr)
{
    var nonConsecutiveInfo = 
          arr.Select((i, index) => new {Index = index, Delta = i - index})
             .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Delta != arr.First());
    
    return nonConsecutiveInfo?.Delta + nonConsecutiveInfo?.Index; 
}
```

Note that this will only work finding non consecutive numbers in ascending order as per requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Let's extract a method:

> Find the first element of an array that is not consecutive ...
>
> If the whole array is consecutive then return `null`

We can implement it like this:

```
private static string FirstInconsecutive(string data) {
  var array = data.Split(',');

  if (array.Length <= 0)
    return null; //TODO: what shall we return on empty array?

  if (!int.TryParse(array[0], out int delta))
    return array[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; ++i)
    if (!int.TryParse(array[i], out int value) || value - i != delta)
      return array[i];

  return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
string result = FirstInconsecutive(txtInput.Text);
```

Please note `int.TryParse` which helps to return the right answer `"ABC"` on an input like `"1, 2, 3, ABC, 4, 6, 7, 8"` (user input `txtInput.Text` can contain any string)

Answer (score 0):

Update your condition as below `for` loop and it will work. I would suggest you to have separate function so that it could be reusable if needed elsewhere in code.

Here start your loop from `i = 1` and compare `numarray[i-1] + 1 != numarray[i]` values.

You can convert your `sting[]` to `int[]` with `var numarray = input.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();` and use it with `IsConsecutive(numarray)` as per `button1_Click` code.

You can get first non-consecutive value with minor modification in `return type` and `return` statement as shown in `GetFirstNonConsecutiveValue()`.

```
public bool IsConsecutive(int[] numarray)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < numarray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numarray[i-1] + 1 != numarray[i])
        {
            return false;
        }                
    }
    return true;
}

public int? GetFirstNonConsecutiveValue(int[] numarray)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < numarray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numarray[i-1] + 1 != numarray[i])
        {
            return numarray[i];
        }                
    }
    return null;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var input = this.txtInput.Text;
    var numarray = input.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();

    var nonConsecutiveValue = GetFirstNonConsecutiveValue(numarray);
    if (nonConsecutiveValue != null)
    {
        // nonConsecutiveValue is first non consecutive value.
    }
    else
    {
        // sequence is consecutive.
    }       
}
```

Comment: The requirement was to find the first non-consecutive element (or null) - so you need to modify your return values.

Answer (score 0):

Two numbers are not consecutive if the left ones + 1 <> the right one.

Check with something like this, note that you have to change your boundary checks:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < numarray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(numarray[i]) + 1 != Convert.ToInt32(numarray[i+1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go.

```
string rawData = "1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9";
IEnumerable<int> data = rawData.Split(',').Select(v => Convert.ToInt32(v));
IEnumerable<int> all = Enumerable.Range(data.Min(), data.Max() - data.Min() + 1);
IEnumerable<int> diff = all.Except(data);
if (diff.Count() == 0)
{
  return null;
}
return data.ElementAt(all.ToList().IndexOf(diff.First()))
```

NB Not thoroughly tested.

Just test diff for being empty to get the numbers are consecutive

Comment: Please, be careful with `Enumerable.Range`: `string rawData = "1,2,3,4,6,7,8,1234567890";` will cause troubles

Comment: Another potential problem is *integer overflow* with `data.Max() - data.Min()`, e.g. for `string rawData = "-1234567890,2,3,4,6,7,8,1234567890";` input

Comment: I was going on the OPs very constrained input data and operating on the assumption that some care had already been taken. Could fix that issue, just by moving to long.